# Bring gameObject to the position of Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to make my object come towards the view port of camera with some offset. Right now I am making the object come at the position of the camera adding some offset to it. The issue is the object is sometimes behind the camera and sometimes in front. But I would like to have equal offset such that it is visible in the viewport of my camera's field of view.

How do I do this?

```
public GameObject camera;
public float offset;

public void Start(){

this.transform.position = new Vector3(camera.transform.position.x + offset, camera.transform.postion.y, camera.transform.position.z + offset);

}
```

Comment: To achieve this you could get the normalized vector of the cameras viewing direction and multiply it with your offset. Then add this Vector to the cameras position and assign the new Vector to the gameObjects transform.position.

Comment: Yes, I did it this way ```this.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.forward * offset);``` but it is never in the center of camera's fov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the following code does is it places the GameObject to be in front of the camera, and off to the side with some offset.

```
public GameObject camera;
public float offsetX;
public float offsetZ;

public void Start(){

this.transform.position = camera.transform.position + camera.transform.forward * offsetZ + camera.transform.right * offsetX;

}
```

Setting the offsetX to be positive moves it towards the right side of the view, while negative does the opposite. Setting the offsetZ increases or decreases the distance from the camera. Setting to negative will put the object behind the camera.